# MS Access Queries Conversion to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am converting lots of access queries to sql server stored procedure. So the sql need to meet the t-sql standard. For example IIF etc
Is there a tool that can convert big access queries to t-sql ? What is the best way of doing this ?

Comment: Sorry, but I believe that best way is to translate query by query manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as a "tool" that will just convert the queries for you, I'm not aware of one. Neither is anyone on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794656/convert-tsql-to-ms-access-sql) or [this site](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/A_13216-Migrating-your-Access-Queries-to-SQL-Server-Transact-SQL.html).

There are a couple places I can direct you, though, that can possibly help with the transition.

[Here is a cheat sheet you can use as a quick glance when converting your queries.](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/30/Quick-Access-JET-SQL-to-T-SQL-Cheatsheet.aspx)

If your queries use any [Forms]! references, there could also be an issue with that. (I've never tried it, but I am going to assume it doesn't work.)

[This resource](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/what-are-the-main-differences-between-access-and-sql-server.html) has probably the most detailed explanations on things you might need to learn in SQL Server. From stored queries, to handling NULLs to some of the other differences. There are also differences in MS Access SQL compared to T-SQL. Gordon Linoff briefly describes 10 important differences in his [blog](http://blog.data-miners.com/).

1. Access does not support the case statement, so conditional logic is
   done with the non-standard `IIf()` or `Switch()` functions.
2. Access requires parentheses around each pair-wise join, resulting in
   a proliferation of nesting in from clauses that only serves to
   confuse people learning SQL.
3. Access join syntax requires the INNER for INNER JOIN.  While it may
   be a good idea to use inner for clarify, it is often omitted in
   practice (in other databases).
4. Access does not support full outer join.
5. Access does not allow union or union all in subqueries.
6. <strike>Access requires the AS for table aliases. In most databases, this
   is optional, and I prefer to only use as for column aliases. 
   Ironically, the use of as for table aliases is forbidden in Oracle.</strike>
7. <strike>Access uses double quotes to delimit strings (as opposed to single
   quotes) and is the only database (to my knowledge) that uses & as a
   string concatenation operator.</strike>
8. Access uses * for the wildcard in like rather than %.
9. Access allows BETWEEN AND .  This is allowed in other databases, but
   will always evaluate to false.
10. Access does not support window/analytic functions (using the over
     and partition by clauses).

In sum, no, there is no tool that I have seen.

Comment: Some corrections and extensions to Mr. Linoff's blog comments. RE: (1) Access also has a `Switch()` function that is a closer match to `CASE .. WHEN` and can avoid multiple nested `IIf()` functions. RE: (6) No, the `AS` keyword is not required for table aliases; it is optional. RE: (7) Access SQL supports both single-quotes and double-quotes for string literals. Access SQL also supports both `&` and `+` for string concatenation, although they handle Nulls differently.

Comment: Thanks! Great points. I often forget `Switch()` exists. Feel free to edit my answer if you see fit anywhere! 2 minds are greater than 1.