# Migrating SQL Query into MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a very long query in SQL. I would like to migrate the query into MS Access. When I directly try to run the SQL Query in MS Access SQL View, it is showing Formatting Errors. Is there a way to Convert the SQL Query into MS Access?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The way to convert it is to sit down and rewrite it for Access. There is no tool to do this, and if there were it would be off-topic to ask for it here on Stackoverflow. Perhaps if you share the tsql some kind soul here will work it over to Access sql for you. I'm also curious why you are wanting to do this in Access instead of sql server. That feels like going backwards, to me.

Comment: Define 'migrate'.   Are you moving everything including the tables into Access?

Comment: I agree 1000% with @JNevill. This is migrating the wrong direction.

Comment: @JNevill Actually, i have a power bi report. So, if i run it, every time, it is fetching all the data let's say 1 million rows and takes nearly 2-3 hours. So, i am thinking to dump all the data upto last month to access. So, it will be easy to run the power bi report.

Comment: @JimCastro just want the Query results to MS Access table.

Comment: @rocky09 - If you are just using Access to connect to sql-server via ODBC then set the query as a pass-through before running it.  Access skips syntax checking on pass through queries but you may need to remove comments as Access still stumbles over them.

Comment: @rocky09 Power BI doesn't need to reload all the data every time.  You can set how often (if ever) the data should be refreshed.

Comment: @JimCastro i will try and let you know if it works.

Comment: @DBro the report has to refresh hourly. :(

Comment: Won't you have the same problem in Access then?

Comment: @DBro, no, once i have the data in access. The File will be available locally available and Power BI doesn't take much time to interact with local files.

Comment: Why not just create a new table in your sql server that has just the month you care about and set up a job to refresh that table hourly or whatever. It sounds very strange to prop up an entirely new server to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look for this url http://nhsexcel.com/converting-sql-to-access/

I’ve been tripped up by the simplest of select queries due to the slight differences in Access SQL (JET SQL) and T-SQL (used on Microsoft SQL Server).

Eg.

T-SQL Select where Value contains…..

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.episodes
WHERE spell_hrg like 'PB%'
```

in T-SQL the multi character wildcard is % while in Access it is *. Strings are also identified in access with the double speechmark “string” rather than single quotes ‘string’

Access SQL Select where Value contains…..

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.episodes
WHERE spell_hrg like “PB*”
```

String Functions
Match multiple characters
T-SQL:

```
WHERE Value like ‘PB%’
```

Access SQL:

```
WHERE Value like “PB*”
```

Match single characters
T-SQL:

```
WHERE Value like ‘PB0_Z’
```

Access SQL:

```
WHERE Value like “PB0?Z”
```

Trimming blanks
T-SQL:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(Value)
```

Access SQL:

```
TRIM(Value)
```

NULLS
Checking for NULLs
T-SQL:

```
WHERE Value IS NULL
```

Access SQL:

```
WHERE Value IS NULL -- or -- WHERE ISNULL(Value) (note the difference from T-SQL's ISNULL)
```

Converting NULL values
T-SQL:

```
COALESCE(Value, ValueToReturnIfNull) -- or -- ISNULL(Value, ValueToReturnIfNull)
```

Access SQL:

```
NZ(Value, ValueToReturnIfNull)
```

Conditional Expressions
T-SQL:

```
 WHEN Condition THEN ReturnIfTrue ELSE ReturnIfFalse END
```

Access SQL:

```
IIF(Condition, ReturnIfTrue, ReturnIfValue)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you do indeed have a long query with multiple joins in TSQL, prepare for Access SQL bracketing issues.  Your joins all need to be bracketed according to Access SQL syntax.  This link explains it: [Convert TSQL to MS-Access SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794656/convert-tsql-to-ms-access-sql)